# How do I build and install Radiotray-NG from source?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I am trying to learn how to install from source code. I want to move to Spiral Debian but there are some packages that I need to use that are not in the repos.

I am on an Ubuntu install 18.04 LTS and using Radiotray-ng as my test (I know there is a .deb package)

I started the install and was able to troubleshoot most of the errors I encountered but I am stuck on the the line $ sudo dpkg -i ./radiotray-ng_x.y.z__<i386|amd64>.deb

I assume it's looking to install (dpkg -i) from the directory but I don't see that file in the directory.  Do I download the .deb into that directory, if so - why wouldn't I just use the .deb?

Here are the complete instructions.  Thanks for your help

### To Build on Ubuntu:

Install these packages:

```
lsb-release libcurl4-openssl-dev libjsoncpp-dev libxdg-basedir-dev libnotify-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libappindicator3-dev libboost-log-dev libboost-program-options-dev libgtk-3-dev libnotify-dev lsb-release libbsd-dev libncurses5-dev libglibmm-2.4-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 cmake
```

### Build Radiotray-NG & Debian Package

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ebruck/radiotray-ng.git
$ cd radiotray-ng
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
$ make package
$ sudo dpkg -i ./radiotray-ng_x.y.z_<distro>_<i386|amd64>.deb
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Did the preceding steps complete *successfully*? Did `make package` create *any* .deb files in the build directory (`ls *.deb`)

Comment: Yes they did.  In fact, just after I posted, my obsessive nature made me follow the steps that my question asked.  I downloaded the .deb package into the build folder and completed the install.  However, in answer to your question, the .deb package is in the build folder.  Isn't the dpkg -i command looking in the ./radiotray-ng folder?

However, the question I still have is - why not just use the .deb package?  What do the previous steps do that the .deb package does not?

Comment: The `dpkg -i` command is looking for a file with the template `radiotray-ng_x.y.z_<distro>_<i386|amd64>.deb` in the current directory, `./`

Comment: Thanks, so I do understand that what it was looking for.  However, the .deb package was in the build "folder" not in the build "directory", ie./radiotray-ng.  Shouldn't the dpkg -i line read sudo dpkg -i ./radiotray-ng/build... I went back in my treminal and saw the line "CPack: - package: /home/mspringer/radiotray-ng/build/radiotray-ng_0.2.8_ubuntu_18.04_amd64.deb generated"

I know this is basic stuff but I have done dozens & dozens of Google searches and the very basic concepts of building from source aren't that easy to find